# Pivot a table to repeat the first column for each following column

Tags: ms-access, pivot

i'm not sure how to explain so I'll try and write out an example.

I'm currently using an access database with a table in the following format

- 1 A B C D
- 2 A B C D

I'm trying to perform a query that will provide me with an output in the following format:

- 1 A
- 1 B
- 1 C
- 1 D
- 2 A
- 2 B
- ....

Currently this will be performed on a Access Db but later on it will need to be converted to a SQL Server query.

I'm not that fluent in SQL so any help would be welcome :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work wit Access and SQL-Server

```
SELECT ID, A AS Fieldx
FROM tbl 
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, B
FROM tbl 
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, C
FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, D
FROM tbl;
```

specific for SQL-Server:

```
SELECT ID, FieldX FROM 
   (SELECT ID,A,B,C,D   FROM tbl) p
UNPIVOT
   (FieldX for dummyID in (A,B,C,D)) as dummyField
```

Additional information can be found [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/04/23/unpivot.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the info! Looking from the examples this looks very promising :) My only concern is with the "generic" query because this would become a really big one depending on the amount of columns. I have read something about a "Transform" function which would be similar to Pivot, do you happen to have knowledge of this for Access?

Comment: You can find examples here http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2005/01/access_sql_tran.html  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208956(v=office.12).aspx  but if I got you right you are searching for the opposite.

Comment: That indeed seems to be the opposite of what I'm trying to do. ( Same for Crosstab ) I should be able to do what I need to do with the union all and hope that they move the data to a SQL DB soon :)